# CSS: Overriding a property for link

Tags: css

I made a menubar using 'ul' , 'li' and a tag and gave some style to it.

Now I need to have a text on the same page so that i can put some event handling to it.like show / hide a division on click.

Should I use 'a' tag or something else? 
if I use 'a' tag then one more problem, the style gets copied from the one i gave to 'a' earlier.

I want it to have different style. Please suggest.

Comment: add your css to the question, but change your declaration for a to `ul li a`

Comment: i suggest use an id or a class for your menu bar so the style would be exclusively for that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define it like this:

```
.classname a {
    color: red;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomaspolach/VLqA7/

Answer (score 0):

As you made a menu using `<ul>` and `<li>`.  Then to showing a feature like `expand` or `collapse` you can  use `<div>` or `<P>` or any other tag you want to use .

Check this Working Example for collapse and hide the content.

http://jsbin.com/qijimamu/1/edit